# zustand when does selector depends on scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zustand

zutand doc mentioned that you can use selector if a selector doesn't depend on the scope and provide the example below

[image]

I didn't understand the `doesn't depend on scope` part. Could someone provide some examples of when the state depends on the scope so that the selector should not be used?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: It means that the selector function only depends on the state variable passed to it, not any other variables inside Component() so it can be pulled up into a function outside of the component. It's not specific to zustand.

Answer (score 0):

All that means is the selector is a function that only consumes a `state` object and thus has no external dependencies.

> Could someone provide some examples of when the state depends on the
> scope so that the selector should not be used?

Scope wouldn't affect when or where a selector function could be used, but rather where it can be declared. Selector functions without dependencies other than `state` can be declared external to any component using them.

You could write a selector function that also references a value defined in the component, so the value would be an external dependency.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const value = ......;

  const selector = state = {
    // use enclosed value to compute returned value from state
    ... do something with value
  };

  const valueFromState = useStore(selector);

  ...
```